# how to stop that while 1 loop by using key interrupt?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, monitoring

```
import os

import win32file
import win32con

ACTIONS = {
  1 : "Created",
}

FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY = 0x0001

path_to_watch = "."
hDir = win32file.CreateFile (
  path_to_watch,
  FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY,
  win32con.FILE_SHARE_READ | win32con.FILE_SHARE_WRITE | win32con.FILE_SHARE_DELETE,
  None,
  win32con.OPEN_EXISTING,
  win32con.FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS,
  None
)
try:
    while 1:
        print("file monitoring started")
        results = win32file.ReadDirectoryChangesW (
            hDir,
            1024,
            True, 
            win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME ,
            None,
            None
        )
        for action, file in results:
            full_filename = os.path.join (path_to_watch, file)
        if action == 1:  
            print (full_filename, ACTIONS.get (action, "Unknown"))
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("exited")
```

Comment: Hi, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Keyboard Interrupt is usually sent by Ctrl-C

Answer (score 0):

You can try somthing like this...

```
while 1:
    try:
        '''
        Your code
        '''
    except KeyboardInterrupt as exception:
        break
```